# Iomega 750 ZIP ATAPI question

Tags: disk, storage, floppy, scsi

Hello I have a Z750ATAPI 750MB Internal Zip Drive.

Drive is using an IDE to SATA converter.

I have read that some people use USB converters for this, but I do not wish to go that route.

Cannot seem to get Ubuntu to see it.

BIOS does detect upon boot.

Running 5.13.0-40-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu

Drive is known to  be working in last Windows machine it was in.

```
sda                       8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk   
└─isw_bggcabbigg_- RAID
                        253:1    0 447.1G  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_bggcabbigg_-RAID1
  │                     253:0    0   512M  0 part   /boot/efi
  └─isw_bggcabbigg_-RAID2
                        253:2    0 446.7G  0 part   /boot
sdb                       8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk   
└─isw_bggcabbigg_-RAID
                        253:1    0 447.1G  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_bggcabbigg_-RAID1
  │                     253:0    0   512M  0 part   /boot/efi
  └─isw_bggcabbigg_-RAID2
                        253:2    0 446.7G  0 part   /boot
sdc                       8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk   
├─sdc1                    8:33   0    10G  0 part   
├─sdc2                    8:34   0   512M  0 part   [SWAP]
├─sdc3                    8:35   0    14G  0 part   
└─sdc4                    8:36   0   1.8T  0 part   
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom    

cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: ADATA SU635      Rev: 0A0 
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: SK hynix SC311 S Rev: 0P10
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi4 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ASUS     Model: DRW-24B1ST   c   Rev: 1.05
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi5 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: WDC WD20PURZ-85G Rev: 0A80
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

I'm open to any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re using (1) whether the Zip Drive has worked in the past or if this is a new setup (2) any additional hardware details that may be useful. With this, it may be possible to offer some suggestions 

Comment: 5.13.0-40-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 09:38:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

as far as the drive, it has worked in the past with no issue in Windows.  I have made the switch over to Linux and have excepted to run into quirks.

As far as additional hardware details, what would you like to know?